# Extending the "String" Class in Rails 2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I'm writing an extension to the String class as such:

```
#/lib/string.rb
Class String
   def linkme
     return self.gsub("[/link]", "</a>").gsub("[link=", "<a href='").gsub("]", "' target='_new'>")
   end
end
```

When I call it in the console, however, I get this:

```
>>require 'lib/string'
SyntaxError: ./lib/string.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/path/to/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /home/path/to/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/path/to/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from (irb):11
```

I figured this should work in theory, as I don't have any...

```
<geek_humor> loose "end"s </geek_humor>
```

This is my first attempt at really trying to extend a class like this in Ruby, and I thought I was doing pretty well, but maybe the S/O community can help me wrap it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
class String
  def linkme
    self.gsub("[/link]", "</a>").gsub("[link=", "<a href='").gsub("]", "' target='_new'>")
  end
end
```

Comment: Nope, same issue. That's actually how I had it originally, and I thought Rails was mega fussy, but that wasn't it

Comment: Oh! no, I take it back. I had my "Class" capitalized... Good call.

Comment: I've just tested it - works perfect. Ehmmm. What Ruby version do you use?

Comment: I thought you were just mistyped with capitalized "Class"